# Can I overamplify a microphone input?

Tags: sound, input

I am experiencing a persistent problem with sound input from internal microphone on my ASUS K52F laptop (iCore M350, Ubuntu 10.10). It produces low level Skype input. Is it possible artificially amplify input level, by mean of software/tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on the Sound Menu (icon at the top right) > Sound Preferences > Input

There is a slider that allows you amplify the input volume level manually, even beyond 100%.

Also you may want to go into Skype > Options > Sound Devices and deselect "Allow Skype to automatically adjust my mixer levels". Skype is defaulted to change your levels for you.

Comment: Thank you tibbyyo for hint. I would like to amplify input volume behind this level. Perhaps it's issue of integrated microphone of my laptop, but I think it's a software issue.

Comment: That's probably a good bet that it's a software problem. If you look around in the Gnome ALSA Mixer, there are more settings for mic input. Other than that I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Low level of mic input could be a software problem. I was thinking of solution like VLC (VideoLan player) for amplified audio output (you may notice that VLC is able to gain about 200% of normal sound level).

Comment: Looks like in 11.10 over-amplifying works well :) Thanks for previous comments.